# Is there a way to check when a user was mapped as DB Owner?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a user that was mapped to a database as DB Owner.

Is there a way to see when this mapping was granted?

Comment: What platform?  SQL Server?  What version?

Comment: it is MS SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a DDL trigger (or some monitoring software) capturing that, you are out of luck.